# Merge pandas dataframes while keeping duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, A and B, which contain different kinds of data. Dataframe A consists of multiple different measurements of an object which where taken at the same time as well as the corresponding timestamp. So a single timestamp will have multiple entries. Dataframe B contains additional data with timestamps that overlap with A. Similar to A the timestamps here also contain multiple entries for the same timestamp but not the same amount as A. B also has more rows than A.

I am interested in assigning a specific value from B to A where the timestamps match, creating a new column for A. For the same timestamp that value is going to be consistent.

My first instinct was to simply use the merge function, however this creates a much larger dataframe caused by the duplicate timestamps. To do that efficiently I extracted only the timestamps from A and the timestamps as well as the value from B.

```
merge = pd.DataFrame(A['time']).merge(B[['time', 'value']], on='time', how='left')
A['value'] = merge['value']
```

Is there a different method that takes the duplicate timestamps into consideration and handles them in the way I need it to?

EDIT: Here is a simplified example of how the data could look like. In this case I would like to assign Value1 to all occurences of '20.08.2023  20:00' and Value2 to '21.08.2023  21:00' in a new column in A.

[Simplified description of the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCCmQ.png)

Comment: Can you give us a sample dataframe A and dataframe B?

Comment: @ChristinaStebbins I just added a simplified example of how the data might look like

Comment: I believe the format I suggested below would work still with that format but I can test if you'd like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that you have two dataframes, A and B, in which A has the following format:

| time | measurement_1 | measurement_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .5 | .4 |
| 1 | .3 | 4 |

and B the format below

| time | value | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | medium | short |
| 1 | medium | tall |
| 1 | medium | short |

The first thing I would look at from a data science perspective, I do not understand why your B will have anything but a single row assigned to your B timestamp (unless if the format is simply timestamp | value where the values have not been split into segregate columns) nor your dataframe A. But, my suggestion would be as follows:

```
C = A.merge(B[['time', 'value']].drop_duplicates(), on='time', how='left')
```

The result is the dataframe below:

| time | measurement_1 | measurement_2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.4 | medium |
| 1 | 0.3 | 4 | medium |

Comment: Dropping the duplicates for dataframe B is exactly what was needed, thank you so much! I really should've gotten that by myself. Regarding the format of B: Sadly that is the format of the data I was given is a result of the measurement process and database handling which is out of my control.

Comment: Getting that kinda data is always frustrating, but happy that I could offer an alternate solution :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`:

```
dfA["value"] = dfA["Time A"].map(dict(zip(dfB["Time B"],dfB["Value B"])))

>>> dfA

                Time A   value
0  2023-08-20 20:00:00  Value1
1  2023-08-20 20:00:00  Value1
2  2023-08-20 20:00:00  Value1
3  2023-08-20 20:00:00  Value1
4  2023-08-20 20:00:00  Value1
5  2023-08-20 20:00:00  Value1
6  2023-08-20 20:00:00  Value1
7  2023-08-21 21:00:00  Value2
8  2023-08-21 21:00:00  Value2
9  2023-08-21 21:00:00  Value2
10 2023-08-21 21:00:00  Value2
```